# Sort Dates in Chronological order in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, anaconda

Can anyone suggest me how to sort the dates in Pandas? I tried some methods but couldn't able to get desired result

```
Index      Date       Confirmed
0      01-01-2020          2
1      01-02-2020          3
2      01-03-2020       1834
3      02-01-2020         23
4      02-02-2020          3
5      02-03-2020          5
```

Comment: please add your sample data as text format not image

Comment: Something like this `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date)` then `df.sort_values(by='date')`

Comment: I did that but some values are sorted properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert column type to `datetime` using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) then sort using [`pd.DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and then [reset](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) index.

```py
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, dayfirst=True)
df = df.sort_values('Date').reset_index(drop=True)
df
        Date  Confirmed
0 2020-01-01          2
1 2020-01-02         23
2 2020-02-01          3
3 2020-02-02          3
4 2020-03-01       1834
5 2020-03-02          5
```

Comment: Hey Thank you friend.Can you tell me after sorting in which format the dates will be arranged ? Is it y/m/d ?

Comment: yes probably...

Comment: What is your date format? `%d-%m-%Y` or `%m-%d-%Y`

Comment: %d-%m-%Y  Some of the date values are present like this and are present in other format. This happens after sort command. Does this have anything to do with groupby.sum() command I used earlier ? I used that to eliminate the recurring dates and sum the Confirmed Column values

Comment: @Keerthishan sorry for confusion i have update my answer try new one

Comment: Thank you friend. I did that now all dates are in ascending order.But the confirmed column values are still interchanged .I found that the dates are only changing not the Confirmed column values

Comment: in Second line make sure you are using `df = df.sort_values(...` not this `df.Date = df.sort_values('...`

Comment: Thank you my friend.I got the answer.Thank you so much!